# Facing Spring Roo issue while converting JPA project to non-JPA project

Tags: mybatis, spring-roo

I have a Spring - JPA project generated using Spring Roo. Now for some requirement we are replacing our JPA layer with some other framework (MyBatis) which is not JPA-compliant. I have done the changes and they are working fine also. I have removed all the JPA dependencies from my pom.xml file.

I am facing issues with my JUnit test project which is used to test DAO layer. Spring Roo is looking for the `javax.persistence.Entity` class which is part of JPA specific jar.

Please find below the error details below:

```
can't determine annotations of missing type javax.persistence.Entity  
when weaving type ****.**.***Test  
when weaving classes  
when weaving  
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=12 AopXmls=#0
[Xlint:cantFindType]
error at (no source information available
```

Can anyone please advise me how to remove this error without adding a JPA dependency?

Comment: Is this error appearing on the Spring Roo shell?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a `push-in` from your test `.aj` file to the related `.java` file and then remove the necessary code (imports, annotations) that makes that your Spring Roo shell shows that error.

If you are not sure about how to make a push-in, you could read Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/removing.html#removing-step-by-step-1

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have already removed those things from my project but still at the time of junit test execution its trying to find the javax.persistence.Entity class. Just to add more information, we are using Aspectj maven plugin for goal test-compile. So I am facing this issue only at the time of execution of the test cases.

Comment: This error is not thrown by Spring-Roo. I think it's thrown by Aspectj compiler *in compilation time*. Review all _*.aj_ and _*.java _ files of `src/test/java` to identify any annotation which could have references to `javax.persistence` package. Good luck!